# OneDrive automatically renames folders. Unable to access local files on my computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, onedrive

I am using Windows 10. I use OneDrive to sync some folders between a Windows 10 pc (where i phisically keep the files) and a Mac that I rarely use. Recently I noticed that a folder in my OneDrive was renamed: the original name was "Università" while the actual name I see now is "UNIVER~1-Davide-PC-57434". The OneDrive icon in the taskbar shows constant sync but it doesn't ever finish and it doesn't tell me what it is synchronising.

If I click on the "UNIVER~1-Davide-PC-57434" folder I can't open it since I get an error. The error says that this folder is not available on my pc but that's impossible since I created this folder in this pc! If I hover the mouse over the I see "sync suspended".

What do i do now?

Comment: Did you check what the web interface for OneDrive shows?

Comment: In the web interface I see the  "UNIVER~1-Davide-PC-57434" folder in addition to a seemingly identical "UNIVER~1" folder.

Comment: Yes, the new folder is a collision. A collision occurred and OneDrive generated a new copy of the folder and appended the name of the computer to it. Go in to the web interface and check the contents of each and manually recombine them. If you haven’t made changes to the files in the new folder you can probably just delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe resetting onedrive fixes the problem:

Press **Windows + R** to open run command

Type the following command and press **ENTER**:

**%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe /reset**

Look at the notification area and check if the onedrive icon disappears and comes back within the next 2 minutes or so.

If it doesn't come back open the run command again and type:

%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe

Onedrive should do some syncing now. When it is finished check if you can access your folder.